# javascript append only first item

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this

```
$("#tableid").append("<tr><td><img id='theImg' src='/assets/logo.png'/></td><td><b>" + section +
            "</b></td><td><b>" + no + "</b></td><td><b>£" + price + "</b></td><td><b>£"+ bookingfee.toFixed(2) +"</b></td><td><b>" + total +"</b></td><td><b>" + button + "</b></td></tr>");
            $("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function() {
                location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
```

How would i go about only making this show the first one of the results rather than showing all of them?

Heres the rest of the js file

```
success: function(json) {
            if (json.total_items == 0 ) {
                $("#tableid").append("<tr><td><img id='theImg' src='/assets/logo.png'/></td><td><b>No Tickets available</b></td></tr>");
            } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < json._embedded.items.length; i++) {
            var section = json._embedded.items[i].seating.section;
            var tid = json._embedded.items[i].id;
            var no = json._embedded.items[i].number_of_tickets;
            var price = json._embedded.items[i].estimated_ticket_price.amount.toFixed(2);
            var bookingfee = json._embedded.items[i].estimated_booking_fee.amount;
            var total = "£" + (parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(bookingfee)).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first one then you shouldn't have used a for loop and replace the `i` with a `0` : `var section = json._embedded.items[0].seating.section;
            var tid = json._embedded.items[0].id;
            var no = json._embedded.items[0].number_of_tickets;
            var price = json._embedded.items[0].estimated_ticket_price.amount.toFixed(2);
            var bookingfee = json._embedded.items[0].estimated_booking_fee.amount;
            var total = "£" + (parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(bookingfee)).toFixed(2)`

Comment: Issue is i use everything else elsehwere, I'm just wanting the first one for an element on my page :)

Comment: Could you give me more details please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the loop and still have only the first element get displayed, I would suggest simply surrounding the part of the code that displays the element with an **if** statement that makes sure that the code will get run only when `i = 0`, i.e. the first element.

```
if (i == 0) {
 $("#tableid").append("<tr><td><img id='theImg' src='/assets/logo.png'/></td><td><b>" + section +
        "</b></td><td><b>" + no + "</b></td><td><b>£" + price + "</b></td><td><b>£"+ bookingfee.toFixed(2) +"</b></td><td><b>" + total +"</b></td><td><b>" + button + "</b></td></tr>");
        $("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function() {
            location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
}
        });
```